# Uninstalling Gstreamer/ updating version in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, gstreamer

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. In an attempt to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50720911/4834108) problem, I installed gstreamer using [this](http://lifestyletransfer.com/how-to-install-gstreamer-from-sources-on-ubuntu/) link. For convenience, I will post the installation script here:

```
# Set your target branch
BRANCH="1.12.5"

exec > >(tee build-gstreamer.log)
exec 2>&1

[ ! -d gstreamer ] && git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gstreamer
[ ! -d gst-plugins-base ] && git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base
[ ! -d gst-plugins-good ] && git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good
[ ! -d gst-plugins-bad ] && git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad
[ ! -d gst-libav ] && git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-libav
[ ! -d gst-plugins-ugly ] && git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-plugins-ugly

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/

cd gstreamer
git checkout $BRANCH
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc
make
sudo make install
cd ..

cd gst-plugins-base
git checkout $BRANCH
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc
make
sudo make install
cd ..

cd gst-plugins-good
git checkout $BRANCH
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc
make
sudo make install
cd ..

cd gst-plugins-bad
git checkout $BRANCH
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc --enable-orc
make
sudo make install
cd ..


cd gst-plugins-ugly
git checkout $BRANCH
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc --enable-orc 
make
sudo make install
cd ..


cd gst-libav
git checkout $BRANCH
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc --enable-orc
make
sudo make install
cd ..

sudo ldconfig
```

After installation I realized that this is not the version(1.12.5) that I need. At this point `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version` returned `GStreamer Core Library version 1.12.5`. So, I tried removing everything by:

```
sudo apt-get remove *gstreamer*
sudo apt-get purge *gstreamer*
```

After running these commands, `dpkg -l|grep gstreamer` returns no results which is expected. I proceeded to install the previous gstreamer version that I had, which is 1.83.x, using commands in the gstreamer website. However, running `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version` still returns `GStreamer Core Library version 1.12.5`.

I think this has to do with `sudo ldconfig` command in the first installation script. I require guidance on undoing those changes.

**Edit1:**
After removing a lot of files and directories, my output for `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version` changed to: `GStreamer Core Library version 1.8.3.` However, `gst-inspect-1.0 --version` gives the output:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.12.5
GStreamer 1.8.3
Unknown package origin
```

How can I fix the version of `gst-inspect`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to check:

```
which gst-inspect-1.0
which gst-launch-1.0
```

Locations for both should be equal.

I had similar problem, but `sudo ldconfig` after `sudo make install` fixed this. Notice that when specifying `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/` (as in your script) forces command `sudo make install` to create *.so files for gstreamer in `/usr/local/lib/`, but gst-inspect-1.0, gst-launch-1.0 use binaries from /usr/lib (not local). So just sync /usr/lib,bin with /usr/local/lib,bin (symlinks or copy). In my case ldconfig after each sudo make install fixed problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I currently don't have a way to check this.

Comment: Worked for me with GStreamer 1.14.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.